# Live search localstorage (search in array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search, object

this is what I what I have:
[image]

And now I want to make the live search. The point is when you type in the textbox you automatically have to search in the localstorage with something that equals the text in the search box. All the data that doesn't matches dissapears.

```
$("#searchbox").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text
    var searchtext = $(this).val();

    // Loop through the local storage
    var a = {};
    a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));

    alert(a);
});
```

As you can see I make an alert and my output is this:

```
{"21114":{"id":"21114","external_id":"","sessiongroupid":"1844","eventid":"5588","order":"0","name":"localStorage
 HTML5 Session","description":"localstorage","starttime":"2013-04-23
 12:00:00","endtime":"2013-04-23
 13:30:00","speaker":"","location":"","mapid":"0","xpos":"0.000000","ypos":"0.000000","maptype":"plan","imageurl":"","presentation":"","organizer":"0","twitter":"","allowAddToFavorites":"0","allowAddToAgenda":"0","votes":"0","url":"","venueid":"0"},"21115":{"id":"21115","external_id":"","sessiongroupid":"1845","eventid":"5588","order":"0","name":"tweede","description":"tweede","starttime":"2013-04-03
 00:00:00","endtime":"2013-04-04
 00:00:00","speaker":"","location":"","mapid":"0","xpos":"0.000000","ypos":"0.000000","maptype":"plan","imageurl":"","presentation":"","organizer":"0","twitter":"","allowAddToFavorites":"0","allowAddToAgenda":"0","votes":"0","url":"","venueid":"0"}}
```

Now I want to search on the name. Can somebody help me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate over the object

```
var json = JSON.parse(localStorage);

for(obj in json) {
    console.log(json[obj].name); //compare this with your "searchtext"
}
```

Prints

```
localStorage HTML5 Session
tweede
```

You can simply check inside the loop if `.name` matches whatever you want and process it.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple code

```
dataArray.filter(function(object) {
   return object.name == new RegExp('text to search', 'gi')
})
```

change .name with your key want to search